# Have a problem to click on checkbox (xPath complex structure)

Tags: xpath

I have a problem and tried many thing (following-sibling, following etc) but couldn't resolve this.
So I have this structure:

```
<li>
 <span>
  <span>
   <input type="checkbox">
  </span>
 </span>
 <div>
  <span>
   <span>Customer</span>
  </span>
 </div>
</li>
```

I have like a checkboxes and I wanna locate on checkbox and click on it where text() attribute is Customer.

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

The XPath to locate checkbox input based on "Customer" text in such XML structure could be:

```xml
"//li[.//span[text()='Customer']]//input[@type='checkbox']"
```